# Oscilloscope Phase Shift

Tags: oscilloscope, high-frequency, pll, phase-shift

I have a university research that i am conducting right now. My objective, as a first step, would be to phase shift an NRZ signal at high frequencies >40GHz, assuming this signal is already locked using a PLL.

We were advice to start by finding a way or the circuitry that can coarse phase shift the signal first by 45degrees, and then fine shift the signal to the smallest degree possible. I have searched but haven't found any help online or in IEEE papers, they are usually ambiguous or not very specific.

I would like to know if this accurate small phase shift is possible at high frequencies and what is the circuitry involved.

Comment: Your title mentions an oscilloscope, but your text says nothing about how an oscilloscope is involved in the problem.

Comment: That would be because this research is about how the high frequency oscilloscopes work. Sorry I didn’t explain more.

Comment: If you're designing an oscilloscope, don't phase shift the measurement signal, phase shift the trigger or sampling clock.

Comment: Please edit the question to make it clear what your problem is and what you're asking about it.

Comment: If you're designing an oscilloscope, you don't want phase shift, you want time shift. What's the difference? If you apply the delay to a signal of a different frequency, then you get the same time shift but a different phase shift. Very small shifts can be got by tapping a transmission line on a board, 1nS/ft in air, up to 2nS/ft on FR4. Longer shifts by tapping an 'artificial transmission line' made up of gate delays or LC sections. This applies whether you're delaying the signal, or delaying the sampling clocks of parallel ADCs or S/Hs.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking exactly, but an [all-pass filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-pass_filter) can be used to produce an arbitrary phase shift or delay. This can be done in either the analog (continuous time) or digital (sampled) domains -- in the latter, you can even shift by a fraction of the sample period.

Comment: Move the receiver 1.25mm further away from the transmitter. For fine adjustment, mount both on a micrometer.